# Show Raw Data From PivotTable

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

In Excel, I have a PivotTable. I'd like to see all of the cells that went into individual calculation. For instance, if I would like to see all the individual values that made up B@ (Mark/Profit) in the PivotTable below, and have them displayed as a column, how would I do that?

```
|      | Profit | Loss |
|------|--------|------|
| Mark | 5      | 10   |
| John | 7      | 8    |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see all cells that went into the calculation, double-click the cell that holds the value.

A new sheet will open that shows the rows that were used.

Check [documentation](https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Expand-collapse-or-show-details-in-a-PivotTable-or--PivotChart-report-0cae5f7a-fee9-4f66-8b76-06bad6cdb14d#bm4)

Comment: Wow! I had no idea that existed. Is there any way to get just the column that's being used? In addition, can I get this for multiple cells in separate columns?